# Spatial Reference for Esri and OneMap

Tags: javascript, dojo, maps

Basically I am trying to perform a search and from the search results, I zoom to certain map level and show the exact location. Here is my html:

```
<div id='top-bar'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style='width:90%;'><input placeholder='Enter An Address' id='search-box' type='text'/></td>
                <td id='search-button'><img id='search-icon' src='img/search.png' width='20' height='20' onClick='GetSearchData()'/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id='searchResults'></div>
    </div>
```

And my javaScript:

```
function setMap()
{
    function init() 
    {
        require(
            [
                "esri/map",
                "dojo/dom-construct",
                "dojo/domReady!"
            ], 
            function
            (
                Map,
                domConstruct
            )
            {
                map = Map("map-canvas",
                {
                });
                map.setZoom(1);
                coreFunctions();
            });

    }
    dojo.ready(init);
}

function GetSearchData() {
    var basicSearch = new BasicSearch;
    var searchText = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
    basicSearch.searchVal = searchText;
    basicSearch.returnGeom = '1';     

    basicSearch.GetSearchResults(displayData);
}

function displayData(resultData){
        var results = resultData.results;
        if (results=='No results'){
            document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = "No result(s) found";
            return false
        }
        else{
            var htmlStr = "<table style='overflow-y: scroll; min-height: 100px;'>";
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var row = results[i];
                htmlStr = htmlStr + "<tr>";
                htmlStr = htmlStr + "<td>";
                htmlStr = htmlStr + "<a href='JavaScript:ZoomTo("+ row.X +","+ row.Y +")'>" + row.SEARCHVAL + "</a>";
                htmlStr = htmlStr + "</td>";
                htmlStr = htmlStr + "</tr>";
            }
            htmlStr = htmlStr + "</table>";
            document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = htmlStr;
        }
    }

function ZoomTo(xVal,yVal){
    map.showLocation(xVal,yVal);
}
```

The search did shows some results. But when I click on one of the search results, it does not perform the zoom function. Instead, it shows me some error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'showLocation'`.

I wonder why is it so as I did followed the documnentation here: [OneMap API](http://www.onemap.sg/api/help/)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I think the problem was with spatial reference. One of the coordinates is 24607.8257, 46287.3873. But I remember the lat and long for Singapore map is 1.352083000000000000, 103.819836000000010000. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

```
function ZoomTo(xVal,yVal){
var pt = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(new esri.geometry.Point(xVal, yVal));
map.centerAndZoom(pt, 5);
}
```

Comment: have you tried if `map` is already defined when you are calling the `ZoomTo` function?

Comment: @DaKirsche Yeah I thought I defined the map in init() ?

Comment: You should try. add `if (!map || !map.showLocation || typeof(map.showLocation) !== 'function'){ alert('map is undefined'); return;}` into your `ZoomTo` function and give it a try.

Comment: @DaKirsche I was wondering is it because of the map spatial reference problem? And it does not execute the ZoomTo at all

Comment: @DaKirsche Can you see my edited portion for ZoomTo() ?

Comment: HI there! Wonder if there's a function called showLocation because the Map itself doesn't have such a function implementet. Check here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html

Answer (score 0):

I wont post code in the comments so here's the Example i mentioned above.

```
require([
   "esri/map", "esri/geometry/Point", "esri/SpatialReference",
   "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/Graphic", ... 
    ], function(Map, Point, SpatialReference, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Graphic, ... ) {
    });

    var map = new Map( ... );
    map.on("load", function() { ShowLocation(-81.3765, 28.54175); });

 function ShowLocation(x, y) {
   var point = new Point(x, y, new SpatialReference({wkid:4326}));
   var simpleMarkerSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
   var graphic = new Graphic(point, simpleMarkerSymbol);

   map.graphics.add(graphic);
 };
```

Also there seems to be an error how you defined your map. If you don't defined your Variable as a global you must there must be a var at the beginning and "new map" instead of map.

```
 var map = new Map("map-canvas",...
```

**UPDATE**

Have you set your spatialreference when defining your Map?

Like :

```
var spatialRef = new SpatialReference({wkid:yourSpatialReferenceHere});
 map = new Map("map", {
                    extent: Extent,
                    spatialReference:spatialRef,
                    lods:lods,
                    logo: false,
                    autoResize:true,
                    sliderStyle: "large",
                    displayGraphicsOnPan: false
                });
```

This should solve the Problem with the different Reference.

Comment: Can you help me take a look at this thread when you free? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196392/map-spatial-reference Because I think the zoomToSegment() has the same problem as the difference in spatial reference